# Nav bar is floating towards left and is not fixed at center position across all devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar which is floating towards left and when i try to login on other devices or bigger screens.. The nav bar floats towards right. How to make navbar fixed at top center position across all devices. Is there any bootstrap property or anything I need to set.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navcolor" style="top:50px;">
    <div style="padding-top:10px">
        <div class="pull-right SocialMore">


        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-top:20px">
            <div class="navbar-brand" style="position:relative;"><img src="" class="logo" /></div>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">

                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <img class="navbar-brand" src="" />
        </div>
        @if (Request.Url.Host.Contains("local"))
        {
            @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/_MainTopMenu.html")))
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/_MainTopMenu.html")))
        }

    </div>
</nav>
```

I tried few padding and margins but it does not work on all screens. Is there a way to make this in center always across all screens

Comment: It looks like you're using the Bootstrap 3 navbar? Are you actually trying to use Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Its bootstrap 4

Comment: Then [read the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) and use the appropriate Bootstrap 4 Navbar structure and classes.